# QT + OpenGL loop event

Tags: qt, python-3.x, opengl

Is there a trigger or signal or event that acts like QWindow.KeyPressEvent(), but instead triggers every time the loop is called?

I'm using Python3, PyQt5 and PyOpenGL to create an OpenGL widget inside of a QT window so I can draw some 2-dimensional objects (maybe 3d someday in the future). I've got a context working, and can draw some objects, but I'd like it to update regularly. Right now I have a method in my OpenGL Window class that overrides keyPressEvent. This works fine for one-time renders, but it also limits the loop. What I'd like is for my OpenGL widget to be rendered every time the QT loop comes around.

Disclaimer: I know that would max my CPU pretty quick, so I'm using a QTimer to wait up to 16ms every time (depending on how much time it takes to render the scene), limit it to no more than 60 renders per second.

Any help is appreciated, and if you have a criticism to this approach of rendering in general, let me know! Thanks.

Edit: I've tried manually calling my render with a timer. The problem is, I can't find a way to make the timer itself fire off more than once! (I'm not using a singleshot) I can't figure out where the timer would go. Once I call my window.show(), it constructs itself, paints my scene once, and waits for events. If I put the timer before the window is shown, my scene will error out (nothing to paint to). If I add the timer in the init of my window class, it fires off only once. And, of course, if I put it in the class I use to update the window, it will recursively call itself before finishing (I can't imagine my RAM will appreceate...)

That's why I'm looking for a signal that is on as long as my window is shown or my application is running--something like a QEvent::WindowActivated instead of QEvent::WindowActivate . A signal that is always on.

I feel like I may be barking up the wrong tree, but I'm not sure how else to tackle the problem.

Comment: I don't get it, what's wrong with using a timer?

Comment: Create a timer that fires periodically. As long as you keep the amount of work done in the timer fairly small it works fine. The resolution of timers is dependent on the operating system. You can also create the main loop yourself and add your idle processing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Enlightenment! You are right, peppe. The timer does work, I was putting it in the wrong place. The place I didn't think of was putting it in the main functions after calling window.show(). Here is what I was doing, and what worked:

```
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Window stuff here
        loop=QtCore.QTimer()
        loop.timeout.connect(gl.update)
        loop.start(0)

class gl(gl.GLWindow):
    def update(self):
        print('x')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    printing=printingclass()
    window = mainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I needed to do:

```
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Window stuff here

class gl(gl.GLWindow):
    def update(self):
        print('x')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    printing=printingclass()
    window = mainWindow()
    window.show()
    loop=QtCore.QTimer()
    loop.timeout.connect(gl.update)
    loop.start(0)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Combining that with another timer that waits up to 17ms, depending on render time, I can limit my renders to 60fps (or whatever framerate I'm shooting for).